# AWS DocumentDB BulkUpdate Long Running Time

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

I'm still a newbie to MongoDB/ non-relational model data stores (coming from experience in BI/DWH, relational DB's), so am struggling a bit with trying to understand how to write MongoDB.  Please be gentle. :)

MongoDB Version: 3.6.0

Here's the problem:

- I have a collection in a DB in an AWS Document DB instance.
- This collection represents about 1.5TB of disk space.  one of the fields was, for a long time, had been writing as a String datatype, though it is actually a date field.  In order to properly query that collection, I need to change the datatype from a String to a Date.
  To do this i've written this query:

```
var bulk = db.collection_name.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var counter = 0;
db.collection_name.find().forEach(function(data) {    var updoc = {        "$set": {}    };
     var myKey = "snapshot_date";
     updoc["$set"][myKey] = new Date(data.snapshot_date);
     bulk.find({        "_id": data._id    }).update(updoc);
     counter++;
     if (counter % 1000 == 0) { bulk.execute(); bulk = db.collection_name.initializeOrderedBulkOp();    }});
```

I started this query this past Monday (two days ago), and it is still running.  I've checked to see that it is still running, and I see that it the engine is running, and cloudwatch shows activity on the CPU utilization, free memory, and documents being updated.

My question: can this query be made more efficient?

I'm trying to update every single document without filtering which should and shouldn't get updated, which I know is a lot.

However, even in a relational database, I figure this wouldn't take this long.

Should I try a different technique for getting this collection updated or maybe create a new collection with that dtype specified?

Comment: More information would be helpful before providing possible improvements. (1) How many documents are in the collection? (2) What is the schema of the collection? Rather than update as per your example using 1000 bulk single document updates you'll want to break it up into updates that affect multiple documents.

Comment: @tmcallaghan, can give you some more information.  
1. count of documents in the collection is 775 million, 775000000.
2.  the schema is as follows

`{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5c9f8af85e9c3077830da4e1"),
 "client_number" :,
 "date" : 
 "mm_ref_date" : 
 "first_page" :
 "note_subject" :
 "group_numbers" :
 "snapshot_date" : 
 "claim_number" : 
 "last_update" : 
 "page_count" :
 "note_id" : ,
 "author_id" :,
 "narr_text": texthere}`

Comment: There isn't any nested documents inside other documents, which may not be great document model standard, but is what i'm working with at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

As described you are performing 775mm individual update operations. While performing this in bulk batches of 1000 is better than one at a time it will still require a very long time to complete. Far more performant would be to update ranges of documents in a larger quantity, say 50000, and issuing a multi update. There is enough code in [MongoDB: how to update n records based on ObjectID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24968862/mongodb-how-to-update-n-records-based-on-objectid) to help you update your code for this technique.